# Neural network cost function implementation

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network

I am implementing neural network to train hand written digits in python. Following is the cost function,
[image]

In **`log(1-(h(x))`**, if `h(x)` is 1, then it would result in `log(1-1)`, i.e. `log(0)`. So I'm getting math error.

Im initializing the weights randomly between 10-60. I'm not sure where I have to change and what I have to change!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this formula, `h(x)` is usually a [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function): `h(x)=sigmoid(x)`, so it's never exactly 1.0, unless the activations in the network are too large (which is bad and will cause problems anyway). The same problem is possible with `log(h(x))` when `h(x)=0`, i.e., when x is a large negative number.

If you don't want to worry about numerical issues, simply add a small number before computing the log: `log(h(x) + 1e-10)`.

Other issues:

- Weight initialization in a range `[10, 60]` doesn't look right, they should better be small random numbers, e.g., from `[-0.01, 0.01]`.
- The formula above is computing *binary cross-entropy* loss. If you're working with MNIST, it has 10 classes, so the loss must be *multi-class cross-entropy*. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46291253/712995) for details.

Comment: thank you... it worked...my input consist of only 0 and 255 as they are black and white images and now i changed all 255 to 0. can you suggest me how many hidden nodes and layers can i use for my network? my input layer has 7990 nodes(85x94) and output layer has 10 nodes..

Comment: First, I'd suggest you to rescale your input to `[0, 1]`. As for the layers and their size, it really depends, you can start with 2 layers and cross-validate if more helps

Comment: sorry for the typo! I have changed all 255 to one not zero. Thank you for the help...